# Pylons webhelpers minify file name too long

Tags: python, pylons, minify, helper

I'm using the pylons "minify" webhelper to minify and combine all of my javascript/css files. It seems the helper concatenates all of the file names and uses the result as the name for the combined version. I have a lot of JavaScript files that are being combined and the resulting file name is giving the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 63] File name too long
```

Is there any way to manually specify the file name or shorten it without changing the helper code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicaly MinificationWebHelpers adds following options to the WebHelpers javascript_link and stylesheet_link functions:

- minified (bool): Minifies/reduces as much as possible each of the files passed to it’s minimum size to reduce page load times.
- combined (bool): Joins all files passed into a single one to reduce server requests which in turn reduces page load times.
- beaker_kwargs (dict): override default arguments that will be passed to beaker_cache.
- combined_filename (string): Name of the filename that will be used in conjunction with combined=True

So it looks like you can set combined_filename to whatever you want the name to be

Comment: Hmm, looks like pylons implements its own minify helper that does not have the "combined_filename" option. I installed MinificationWebHelpers and that seems to be working though, thanks.